# half the dimension of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Lets say I have a numpy array of 4x4 dimension and want to change it to 2x2 by taking its halve. So, theoretically do something like this:

[image]

is this possible without using any loop and for it to work on not only a 4x4 but lets say a 500x500?

```
#input:
x_4= np.array([[1, 2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 6, 8], [5, 3, 1, -1], [2, 3, 5, 0]])

# thinking it would work with something like this:
new = x_4[:2, :2]/4 + x_4[:2, -2:]/4 + x_4[-2:, :2]/4 + x_4[-2:, -2:]/4
new
# output: array([[11,  9],[16, 15]])

#Expected output: array([[2.5, 5.75], [3.25, 1.25]])
```

Comment: Yes! This operation is called _average pooling_.

Comment: both solutions work perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Numpy Version:**

you can do a reshape and perform mean over two axis to get the desired result

```
import numpy as np

blocksize = 500

Mat = np.random.rand(blocksize,blocksize)

## reshape into (blocksize/2 x blocksize/2 ) 2x2 matrices

blocks = Mat.reshape(blocksize//2, 2, blocksize//2, 2)

block_mean = np.mean(blocks, axis=(1,-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in the comments, you can use pooling, which is e.g. available in the scikit-image package:

```
import skimage.measure
shape = (2, 2)
skimage.measure.block_reduce(x_4, shape, np.mean)
```

Where shape gives you the dimensions of your pools.

Answer (score 0):

This Operation called average Pooling it used in CNN and image processing to reduce the dimension of the image
you can use `TensorFlow` or `PyTorch` first you need to reshape the image to `(batch_size,Channels,Rows,Columns)` for PyTorch to work

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch import nn
m= nn.AvgPool2d(2, stride=2)
x_4= np.array([[1, 2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 6, 8], [5, 3, 1, -1], [2, 3, 5, 0]])
x_4=x_4[None,None,:,:]
x_4=torch.as_tensor(x_4,dtype=torch.float64)
x_4.shape
m(x_4).numpy()
```

### Output

```
array([[[[2.5 , 5.75],
         [3.25, 1.25]]]])
```